# What's the intuition behind the tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

Well, when we work with a smooth manifold $M$ we can associate with each point $p\in M$ a vector space $T_p M$ of all vectors at $p$ tangent to $M$: this is the space of linear functionals obeying liebniz rule in the algebra of germs of functions at $p$.

This definition of vector is very intuitive, since it generalizes the main property of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of producing the directional derivative. Now, then we usually say: "well, we must find a way to assemble all of the tangent spaces together to have a domain and range for the derivative", then we define $TM$ as the disjoint union of all $T_p M$ and if $\pi : TM \to M$ is the projection on the first coordinate, we want to construct a vector bundle $\pi : TM \to M$.

Now, what doesn't seem clear to me is why do we want the structure of a vector bundle. The definition of a fiber bundle is meant as I understand, to make a space that locally looks like a product space, but why do we want this? Is this because $T\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and we want to ``copy'' this behavior locally?

Also, how do we know that there's an obstruction in general to write $TM = M \times \mathbb{R}^n$? I've seem a question like this before here and there were answers based on hairy ball theorem and so on. The point is, this result needs that we first define $TM$ as it is define. If we don't know any of these theorems, how do we know that writing $TM$ that way is not possible?

Thanks very much in advance for the aid!

Comment: Well, since $M$ is locally undistinguishable from $\Bbb R^n$, the tangent bundle of $M$, *whatever that may be* must be locally indistinguishable from the tangent bundle of $\Bbb R^n$ which is naturally $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: In some sense you "can" write $TM=M\times \mathbb R^n$, but that is not a complete description of $TM$ -- you also need to specify _how_ each copy of $\mathbb R^n$ represents the tangent space at each point. There's no canonical way to make this identification, and in some cases there isn't even any _continuous_ way to do it, such as if $M$ is a Möbius strip. So it's better to leave the correspondence abstract.

Answer (score 4):

The bundle structure on the set $TM$ explains how it is a manifold in its own right, since one can construct by the bundle's local trivialization *bundle charts*, which map open sets of $TU\subset TM\to U\times\mathbb{R}^m$. It is especially useful for calculating objects on the (tangent) bundle,  e.g. the [Levi-Civita connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), in local coordinates where one needs local trivializations.